# Why is HTML5 progress bar value jumping and lagging on update?

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs

I'm using an html  element as a progress indicator for a video.  I'm attempting to update the video and progress element to a specific time when clicking the progress element e.g. User clicks at the 0:10 mark and the video/indicator are updated accordingly.  My onclick handler looks something like this:

```
<progress
    onClick={e => {
        const percent = e.nativeEvent.offsetX / progressEl.offsetWidth;
        progressEl.value = percent * 100;
        videoEl.currentTime = percent * videoEl.duration;
    }}
    value="0"
    min="0"></progress>
```

This works, except that for a brief second the progress indicator value jumps too far ahead of where the user clicks before snapping back to the correct location. I'm doing this within a reactjs component (which is why I'm using nativeEvent).

Comment: You should show some more code to resolve this..

Comment: I added the element itself.  Is there anything else that would help resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The max of the progress indicator on video load was being set to the total time of the video rather than 100, so I had to adjust the code to take this total into account in order to determine the correct value. The correct code should have been:

```
<progress
    onClick={e => {
        const percent = e.nativeEvent.offsetX / progressEl.offsetWidth;
        progressEl.value = percent * videoEl.duration;
        videoEl.currentTime = percent * videoEl.duration;
    }}
    value="0"
    min="0"></progress>
```